# Issue with submitting form via jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery

I have written a jQuery script that checks for change event on a file input field, when a file is selected, the form submit function needs to be fired and post data via Ajax.

**The Problem:**
Function on file change is being fired but the submit function is not being fired. The console has no errors to show.

Script that I have written:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#upld").on('change', function() {
        console.log('going to run submit function');
        $('#fff').submit(function(e) {
            console.log('submitting function executed')
            var siteSettings = {"ajaxurl": '/filer/check/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'};
            var data = {
                action: 'uploading-new-image',
                files: $(this).serialize()
            };

            jQuery.post(
                    siteSettings.ajaxurl,
                    data,
                    function(response) {
                        $("#error").html(response);
                    });

            e.preventDefault();

        });

    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="fff" method="POST" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="filetoupload" id="upld" />
</form>
```

[**View on JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VxS89/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not triggering it. You are just adding a handler for submit handler.

Add `.submit()` or `.trigger('submit')` to the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#upld").on('change', function () {
        console.log('going to run submit function');
        $('#fff').submit(function (e) {
            console.log('submitting function executed')
            var siteSettings = {
                "ajaxurl": '/filer/check/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
            };
            var data = {
                action: 'uploading-new-image',
                files: $(this).serialize()
            };

            jQuery.post(
            siteSettings.ajaxurl,
            data,

            function (response) {
                $("#error").html(response);
            });

            e.preventDefault();

        }).submit();  //  <-------- Added submit here.
    });
});
```

Comment: thankyou, one more question please, how do I parse $_FILES data of the uploaded file via ajax so that I can deal with it on the Server side PHP script file?

Comment: @Jade, sorry! I don't know php :(